# Looking for script that changes form div upon form submission without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, webforms

I have an email form on an HTML page and once you click submit to send the form submission I would like the DIV "form" to update or be replaced to say a 'Thank you' message.

Tried Googling this, but didn't have much luck finding anything specific that I can use.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with example for You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery.ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/send_mail.php',
  data: "message="+$('#some_field').val(),
  success: function(data) {
    //replace form (form is in div <div id="form"><form>Form data</form></form>)
    $('div#form').html('<p>Thank You!<p>');
    //or $('div#form').html(data); if you are returning message from send_mail.php
  }
});
```

If You are having problems i can write You a whole script (i'm just in the mood and have some spare time):)

UPDATE:

Basically this is it.

Copy/paste this as your form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="hr-HR" lang="hr-HR">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/JavaScript"  charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
 $('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
    url: 'sendit.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form#mail_form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
    if(data.success==1){
   $('div#form').html(data.message);
   }
    }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="form">
  <form id="mail_form">
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/>
  </div>
  <div>
   <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send"/>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy/paste this as you sendit.php:
You MUST validate this data

```
//do stuff, send mail, save to database,...
 $data['success']=1;
 $data['message']='Thank You!';
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: How kind of you, thanks. Feel free to do a whole script as this seems to be the best method so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just hide the form using jquery / javascript and show a thank you message div on form submit.
Edit:  Try the following:

```
    <html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("#button").click(function () {
    $("form").hide();
    $("div").show();
    return false;
 });
 });
</script>
<form>
form data<br/>
<button id="button">click me</button>
</form>
<div style="display: none">
thank you
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, that's what I was thinking. Any scripts I can use as I don't have much knowledge of it?

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery's [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('div.the-form').replaceWith('<div class="thankyou">Thanks for your submission.</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a AJAX POST and in the callback you can display "thank you message" (jQuery may help).

The code could look like:

```
$.post('test.do', function(data) {
  $('.confirmation').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div with id 'thankyouDiv' and initially set its `style="display:none;"`. This div should contain your Thank You Message
On submitting the form first hide the div containing the email form and show the 'thankyouDiv' by changing `style="display:block;"` .After that you can submit the form .

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume, this is your markup...

```
...
<div id='formcontainer'>
  <form id='emailform' ....>
  </form>
</div>
..
```

and here is your jQuery code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('emailform').submit(function(){

        // serialize your form to get the data, all do what you want to to...

        // now, do AJAX thing here...
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',  
            url: yourscript.php,
            data: data,             // serialized data, for example
            success: function(){
                // this is performed on success
                $('emailform').hide();          // form will fade out
                $('formcontainer').html('Thanks, the message has been sent')
            }
        });        

        return false;    // this prevent form from real submit
    });
});
```

Let me know the result :)